# Eclipse stopped working and doesn't start

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

My Eclipse suddenly has stopped working and won't start anymore...

tried everything I can, but it wont start, didn't made any changes or something dramatic
I lunched it through `CMD` and this is the log I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPla
tform.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getLog(Plugin.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:821)

        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.logError(StatusManager.ja
va:285)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java
:200)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java
:231)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.
logging(StatusManager.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLo
g.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLo
gWriter.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safe
Logged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logP
rivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(
ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(Extend
edLogServiceFactory.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedL
ogServiceImpl.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformL
ogWriter.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:7
1)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPla
tform.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getLog(Plugin.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:821)

        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.logError(StatusManager.ja
va:285)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java
:200)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java
:231)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.
logging(StatusManager.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLo
g.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLo
gWriter.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safe
Logged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logP
rivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(
ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(Extend
edLogServiceFactory.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedL
ogServiceImpl.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformL
ogWriter.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.handleException(JobListen
ers.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.doNotify(JobListeners.jav
a:98)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:15
2)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.endJob(JobManager.java:647)

        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.endJob(WorkerPool.java:105)

        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:70)
```

Any ideas?

**ADDED**: after deleted `.\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`Eclipse lunched with error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (346).
```

Comment: try running eclipse with `-clean`. So you run it like `eclipse.exe -clean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should delete

1)   ...\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench"

and tell me about the status.

2) There's a .log file in the .metadata directory inside each workspace, which often contains a number of stack traces from the Eclipse internals. Startup crashes are usually found here. I'm assuming you have Eclipse configured to start up in a specific workspace automatically, without prompting you to pick one at startup.

3) add this in eclipse.ini:

-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_5/jre/bin/javaw.exe
And it can work. I change the JRE to JDK/JRE.

JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME Should point to the above location.

Try these methods one by one.. One of them will work. this is like a troubleshooter.

Comment: Thanks, now it's with errors but lunched...I added the new error in my question

Comment: now the thing is u had sdk installed in ur eclipse? install it again.and delete the previous sdk(remains)

Comment: What you mean...I have sdk installed, do I need to uninstall it and install it again?

Comment: yeah. mainly thatand everything is working fine i guess? @dima

Comment: now it works... but with a lot of errors, do I really need to uninstall sdk?

Comment: if your are developing android then yes else no.@Dima